# How to get Pattern as String used for publishing the message in Redis PubSub

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, publish-subscribe, spring-data-redis

I am using below code. pattern is in byte[] type. Have to get the pattern as String for business logic. Is there any way to get it ! Have to make publisher or subscription topic names dynamic.

```
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedis = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedis.setHostName("xxxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net");
        jedis.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=");
        jedis.setPort(6379);
        return jedis;       
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new CustomerInfoSubscriber());
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());       
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), new PatternTopic("*/*"));
        container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));
        return container;
    }
```

### }

```
public class RedisCustomerInfoPublisher implements CustomerInfoPublisher {
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
@Override
public void publish() {
    redisTemplate.convertAndSend("testing/1", "COMING FROM PUBLISHER");
    }
```

### }

```
public class CustomerInfoSubscriber implements MessageListener {    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        System.out.println(" ::::: Pattern 1 is " + pattern.toString() + " ::::: ");
        System.out.println(" ::::: Pattern 2 is " + Arrays.toString(pattern) + " ::::: ");
        System.out.println("Received >> " + message +  ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to get "testing/1" in the listener class. Need help on that part.

Comment: Assuming the byte array correspond to a string, you can simply use `new String(bytes,encoding)` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: If I use System.out.println(new String(pattern)), I am getting ' * / * ' (which is used for registering the listener). But I need to get "testing/1" (which is used for publishing the message)

Answer (score 0):

Though  is too late and already mentioned in the comment, thought to set it clear, for future reference:

```
 System.out.println(new String(pattern, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```